# EF Code first - forgot to run "Add-Migration"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have a Web project which has already been published to the production server. On my development machine, I made some changes on the model class and ran `Update-Database` without run `Add-Migration`. I tried to

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:"201304020555457_previous_migration"
```

but I got the error of

> Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss.

How to roll back so I can get the full SQL script for applying on the production server?

**Update:**

I just published the code, start the page in browser, and the database changes (adding columns) were done after it's executed. I don't need to do anything. Does it means it's really not necessary to run `Add-Migration` every time?

Answer (score 0):

You could undo the changes you made , then run Update-Database.
Then re-make the changes and this time run Add-Migration

Answer (score 0):

If your initializer is *MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion* and your configuration has *AutomaticMigrationsEnabled* set to true then it will update your db without the need for migrations, if it can.

If you really wanted you could only add migrations for changes that your really want documented or you want to modify, You could skip adding simple columns and add migrations for renaming columns for example.

But if i where you I'd keep migrations complete to avoid issues further down the line.